# Apache Jmeter JDBC connection issue - JDBC driver class not found

Tags: apache, jmeter

I am trying to connect to PL/SQL 8.0.4.1514 through JMeter.

In JDBC connection configuration ,I have provided the database URL as `"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//01HW552780:6129))/tnsfile"` and JDBC driver class as `"com.plsql.jdbc.Driver"`

But getting error as `"No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//01HW552780:6129))/tnsfile"`

Could someone rectify me here regarding driver class?

Comment: Do you using Oracle JDBC driver ?

Answer (score 2):

1. I believe that you need `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` class instead.
2. I believe that you need to remove `//` from your JDBC URL
3. I'm not too sure regarding `tnsfile` (unless it is you real oracle database name) as Oracle JDBC URL takes forms:

   - jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port **/databaseName**
   - jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port **:serviceName**
4. Relevant driver can be downloaded from [Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) or alternatively (better) take it from `$ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/` folder on the machine where Oracle lives
5. See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) guide for more configuration and usage details for the JDBC Sampler.

Comment: @ Dmitri,  You are awesome, 90% of times your responses helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem.

1. I used `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` as Driver Class.
2. No need to remove `//`. It can be present.
3. In database URL, it should be `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//MachineName:Port/Schema`
4. Download or better copy JDBC Jars from your DB installation and paste it under `Jmeter/lib` path.
   For example, I presume you DB as Oracle 12c, it required `ojdbc6.jar` and `ojdbc7.jar` copied and pasted under `Jmeter/lib` folder.

After this activity, the problem vanished away for me.